# Javascript - Removing objects from array from filter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am attempting to remove an object from an array if the condition is not met, I'm attempting doing this by using the .filter methods but because the condition is not met its not returning the entire array, but instead I would like it return the array of objects, just not the objects that are equal 0. Is this something that is possible?

Here is a code snippet of what I'm trying:

```js
const data = [{year2010: 0, year2011: 0, year2012: 5463, year2013: 4312, year2014: 3498, year2015: 9342, year2016: 0 }]


let filterData = data.filter(function(item) {
return (item.year2010 !== 0 || item.year2011 !== 0 || item.year2016 !==0)
})

console.log(filterData)
```

Here is a snippet of what I expect my end result to be

```
const data = [{ year2012: 5463, year2013: 4312, year2014: 3498, year2015: 9342 }]
```

Comment: you can remove element from array not from json using filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One straightforward solution is uses `delete object[key]` to remove one property from one object.

So loop all properties in one object by `Object.keys(elementOfArray).map`, then remove the property if its value is 0.

Below is one demo:

```js
const data = [{year2010: 0, year2011: 0, year2012: 5463, year2013: 4312, year2014: 3498, year2015: 9342, year2016: 0 }]
const res = data.map((item) => {
  Object.keys(item).map(key => item[key] == 0 && (delete item[key]))
  return item
})
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should filter `Object.entries` of each element instead and use `Object.fromEntries` to convert the result back to an object.

```js
const data = [{year2010: 0, year2011: 0, year2012: 5463, year2013: 4312, year2014: 3498, year2015: 9342, year2016: 0 }]
const res = data.map(obj=>
   Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([key,val])=>val!==0)));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{year2010: 0, year2011: 0, year2012: 5463, year2013: 4312, year2014: 3498, year2015: 9342, year2016: 0 }]


let filterData = data.map(function(item) {
  const keys = Object.keys(item)
  return keys.filter((rec) => item[rec] !== 0)
    .map(key => {
      return { [key]: item[key] }
    })
})

console.log(filterData)
```